# Error with \input: runaway argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

I have the following two .tex files which won't compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 14pt, pdftex, pdfa]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{comment, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, multicol, graphicx, caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
   \input{man.tex}
\caption{Výpočet odchylky dvou vektorů pomocí kosinové věty}
\label{fig:05}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and `man.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}          
\coordinate (o) at (1,1);
\coordinate (u) at (3,3);
\coordinate (x) at (6,1);
\draw[-latex] (o) -- (u);
\draw[-latex] (o) -- (x);
\draw[-latex] (x) -- (u);
\draw[color=black] (3,1.2) node {$\vec{v}$};
\draw[color=black] (4.92,2.2) node {$\vec{w}$};
\draw[color=black] (1.7,2) node {$\vec{u}$};
\path pic[draw=teal, angle radius=8.5mm, teal, angle eccentricity=1.04]{angle=x--o--u};
\draw[color=teal] (1.49,1.22) node {$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I compile `man.tex` separately (with proper preamble), it works fine. Anyone able to spot the problem?

Comment: the "proper preamble" doesn't contain `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` ... (you need to disable the shorthands or use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`